# Creating a trigger from SQL view

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, database-trigger

I have two tables that are updated by one function (`GLPOST` and `GLPOSTO`).

I have created a view (`GLREP`) based on these two tables that transposes the rows of `GLPOSTO` into columns as this is how I want my data.

Now I want to create a trigger (`OPTIONAL`) on this view to insert to a new table (`GLREPORTEXCEL`) once the view collects the data from the various tables in the view format.

View `GLREP`:

```
CREATE VIEW [dbo].[GLREP] 
AS 
    (SELECT * 
     FROM 
         (SELECT  
              GLPOST.ACCTID,
              JRNLDATE, 
              GLPOST.FISCALYR, 
              GLPOST.FISCALPERD, 
              GLPOST.SRCECURN, 
              GLPOST.BATCHNBR,
              GLPOST.ENTRYNBR, 
              GLPOST.JNLDTLDESC, 
              GLPOST.JNLDTLREF, 
              GLPOST.TRANSAMT,
              GLPOST.CONVRATE,
              GLPOST.SCURNAMT, 
              GLPOSTO.OPTFIELD,
              GLPOST.CNTDETAIL,  
              CSOPTFD.VDESC 
          FROM 
              GLPOST 
          LEFT JOIN 
              GLPOSTO ON GLPOST.ACCTID = GLPOSTO.ACCTID 
                      AND GLPOST.POSTINGSEQ = GLPOSTO.POSTINGSEQ 
                      AND glpost.CNTDETAIL = glposto.CNTDETAIL 
          LEFT JOIN 
              CSOPTFD ON GLPOSTO.OPTFIELD = CSOPTFD.OPTFIELD 
                      AND GLPOSTO.VALUE = CSOPTFD.VALUE) AS source 
     PIVOT
          (MAX([VDESC]) 
              FOR [OPTFIELD] IN (ADVANCE, MEDICAL, MILEAGE, MOTORVEHICLE, PROMOTION, STAFF)) AS PVT 
           )
```

My trigger that is not working:

```
CREATE TRIGGER OPTIONAL
ON GLREP
FOR INSERT
AS
    INSERT INTO GLREPORTEXCEL (ACCTID, TRANDATE, FISCALYR, FISCALPERD, SRCECURN, BATCHNBR, 
                               ENTRYNBR, JNLDTLDESC, JNLDTLREF, TRANSAMT, CONVRATE, SCURNAMT, 
                               CNTDETAIL, STAFF, ADVANCE, MEDICAL, MILEAGE, MOTORVEHICLE, PROMOTION)
        SELECT 
            ACCTID, JRNLDATE, FISCALYR, FISCALPERD, SRCECURN, BATCHNBR, 
            ENTRYNBR, JNLDTLDESC, JNLDTLREF, TRANSAMT, CONVRATE, SCURNAMT, 
            CNTDETAIL, STAFF, ADVANCE, MEDICAL, MILEAGE, MOTORVEHICLE, PROMOTION 
        FROM 
            inserted
```

New table that I want to insert into is called `GLREPORTEXCEL`.

Comment: Why are you SHOUTING? You say your trigger isn't working, but you dont explain why. Please do, as otherwise we can't help you.

Comment: You might want to change the trigger from a `for insert` to an `instead of insert`.

Comment: Views **cannot** have "normal" `FOR INSERT` triggers - you can only define an `INSTEAD OF INSERT` trigger on views

Answer (score 0):

As I hinted and marc specifically wrote in the comments, SQL Server does not support `for` triggers on views - only `instead of` triggers.

This is documented on the [CREATE TRIGGER (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-trigger-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017#arguments) page, in the Arguments paragraph:

> *table | view*
>   The table or view on which the DML trigger runs. This table or view is sometimes referred to as the trigger table or trigger view. Specifying the fully qualified name of the table or view is optional. **You can only reference a view by an INSTEAD OF trigger.** You can't define DML triggers on local or global temporary tables.

(emphasis mine).

This means that you need to change the trigger from a `for` trigger to an `instead of` trigger:

```
CREATE TRIGGER OPTIONAL
ON GLREP
INSTEAD OF INSERT
AS
    INSERT INTO GLREPORTEXCEL (ACCTID, TRANDATE, FISCALYR, FISCALPERD, SRCECURN, BATCHNBR, 
                               ENTRYNBR, JNLDTLDESC, JNLDTLREF, TRANSAMT, CONVRATE, SCURNAMT, 
                               CNTDETAIL, STAFF, ADVANCE, MEDICAL, MILEAGE, MOTORVEHICLE, PROMOTION)
        SELECT 
            ACCTID, JRNLDATE, FISCALYR, FISCALPERD, SRCECURN, BATCHNBR, 
            ENTRYNBR, JNLDTLDESC, JNLDTLREF, TRANSAMT, CONVRATE, SCURNAMT, 
            CNTDETAIL, STAFF, ADVANCE, MEDICAL, MILEAGE, MOTORVEHICLE, PROMOTION 
        FROM 
            inserted
```

Comment: Apologies Larnu  it was mistyping errors.Thanks Zohar, I have created the trigger as suggested above but it does not insert the records  into GLREPORTEXCEL once I have added records in my two tables .(GLPOST &GLPOSTO).

Comment: As should be expected. This trigger will only be fired when an insert statement will be executed on the `GLREP` view itself. Inserting data into it's underlying tables will not fire the trigger on the view. Something tells me that this is an [xyproblem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). What is the purpose of this `GLREPORTEXCEL` table?

Comment: GLREP view has fetched this transaction posted in GLPOST and GLPOSTO.GLREPORTEXCEL is a staging table for two system intergration. I am mining data from one system and populating it in GLREPORTEXCEL for another integrated system to make some updates also in order to give a comprehensive report

Comment: not really sure how that answers my question. Why do you want to store the content of the view in a different table?

Comment: Kindly see my explanation again. I have two tables :GLPOST and GLPOSTO.The data stored in GLPOSTO is in rows but I wanted it transposed to columns.For this reason I used a view GLREP above which works fine.On this stage I have been given table GLREPORTEXCEL by the team managing another system  requesting me to fill my columns above and leave their columns blank as they will update them later.Our two systems are integrated each with its own function but we need a consolidated report.or can I be able to transpose data  as done when creating a view and post direct to GLREPORTEXCEL without view?

Comment: Well, I guess you could use a trigger on the source tables that will insert the data from the view into the target table - however I'm not sure that's such a good idea to begin with. Since you already have the view, I would suggest to let the other team reference it when they need to insert their data into the target table. (of course, if that's a viable option for you).